# Swagger UI not generating JSON param in POST with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger-ui version 3.0.0 and Spring boot version 2.5.2, I am trying to document my REST Api, but I am stuck with POST request, as the swagger ui is not generating JSON for POST parameter instead it generates it as string fields.

Here is my controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/message", 
          produces = { "application/json;charset=utf-8" }, 
          consumes = { "application/json;charset=utf-8" }, 
          method = RequestMethod.POST) 
ResponseEntity<?> createMessage( @RequestBody Message message);
```

Here is my Model:-

```
@ApiModel(description = "")
@Validated
public class Message {
    
      @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull
      @JsonProperty("code")
      private Integer code = null;
      
      @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull
      @JsonProperty("message")
      private String message = null;
```

and below is the image the swagger ui generated for this code:-

[actual swagger ui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDokt.png)

but I wanted it to look like this POST param with object JOSN(This is someone else's code):-

[expected swagger ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbC5l.png)

Comment: Tested with swagger 2.9 + spring boot 2.1.4 and the code works fine.

Comment: can you can can you share screenshot, I suppose it was the version issue then?

Comment: Thanks, it work for me too with swagger 2.9+

Comment: I guess, 3.0 needs to be fixed

Comment: Test with spring boot 2.5.2 + swagger 3.0, also works fine

Comment: Screenshot: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17768055/124362659-eadd1900-dc68-11eb-99d5-98af646be4f1.png)

Answer (score 2):

Mention model class name in ResponseEntity<?>,  which API is returning in response. In your case, looks like Model Class is **Message**.

Here, Instead of defining method like this:

```
ResponseEntity<?> createMessage( @RequestBody Message message);
```

Replace with this:

```
ResponseEntity<Message> createMessage( @RequestBody Message message);
```